# Python row.count error

Tags: python

I am very new to python and have no idea what I'm doing but I am trying to learn as I program as this is what I have done in the past with C, C++, and Cocoa.

I am writing a program with a matrix. I want to count the number of occurrences of x (x being a value in my matrix.) When I try to do this though I am not exactly sure what I am getting. A nice explanation of what I am getting and how to do things with matrices is all I am looking for. Eventually I will want to use the matrix.insert, the matrix.tofile, and the matrix.remove commands as well. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Here is my Code:

```
    matrix = [
    [2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6],
    [8, 1, 1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 1, 3],
    [5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 3, 8, 1, 5],
    [1, 7, 8, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9],
    [3, 8, 6, 3, 1, 7, 4, 9, 6],
    [9, 5, 4, 5, 9, 4, 2, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 9, 6, 1, 1],
    [7, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 1, 5],
    [3, 1, 9, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4],
    ]
for sublist in matrix:
    S = str(sublist)
    print (S)
for row in matrix:
    A = row.count(0)
    B = row.count(1)
    C = row.count(2)
    D = row.count(3)
    E = row.count(4)
    F = row.count(5)
    G = row.count(6)
    H = row.count(7)
    I = row.count(8)
    J = row.count(9)
    print (A)
for row in matrix:
    if A > 0:
        if B < 1:
            print (B)
```

Here is what I get when I run the program:

```
[2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2, 4, 6]
[8, 1, 1, 8, 4, 7, 5, 1, 3]
[5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 3, 8, 1, 5]
[1, 7, 8, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9]
[3, 8, 6, 3, 1, 7, 4, 9, 6]
[9, 5, 4, 5, 9, 4, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 9, 6, 1, 1]
[7, 5, 8, 3, 2, 6, 9, 1, 5]
[3, 1, 9, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4]
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not exactly getting a "matrix" here, it's really a list of lists.

What you're getting from your `for row in matrix` block is the number of times a particular number has occurred, say `9` for the first time around.  You're also not printing any other value besides the occurrence of `0`.

`list.insert(i, v)` will allow you to add a new value `v` at a specific index `i`.  It's helpful if you want to insert something ahead of or after another element in your list.

There is no `list.tofile()` method; you would have to write each individual line out to a file instead.  You should look into file objects, and how to write to a file in the Python documentation.

`list.remove(v)` will remove the **first occurrence** of `v` in your list.

In your last `for row in matrix` block, nothing will be printed; the variables `A` through `J` are localized *only* to the previous loop block.  You can adjust that by adding the two statements to the end of your previous loop, like so:

```
for row in matrix:
    A = row.count(0)
    B = row.count(1)
    C = row.count(2)
    D = row.count(3)
    E = row.count(4)
    F = row.count(5)
    G = row.count(6)
    H = row.count(7)
    I = row.count(8)
    J = row.count(9)
    print (A)
    if A > 0:
        if B < 1:
            print (B)
```

If you're interested in learning about lists a bit more, you should peruse the [documentation](http://docs.python.org), and check out a few tutorials.  There are also a few free e-books available - one of which is [Dive into Python 3](http://www.diveintopython3.net/) - which is a great resource.

---

EDIT:  Taking another look at your code, I've observed that you never actually print out B.  Since the number of zeroes in your "matrix" never exceed zero, you won't be printing out B.  Perhaps in your original question, you could illustrate what you want from the result a bit clearer?  If you have a matrix that, in any of its rows, contains nonzero values, B will never be printed.

Comment: Thank You. What i was having trouble with was the different loops. I understood the way it worked. I have been looking at the documentation it has been helpful. I will also check out this dive into python book.

Comment: I am now having trouble seeing which numbers are A and with ones are B. they seem to alternate is that correct? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're printing those values from A to J sequentially, so we could take a quick look at the "matrix" and see what's being accepted.   A and B should both be zero, since there's no instances of 0 or 1 in the first row.  Again, I strongly encourage you to check the existing documentation, and check the books in addition to this response; you will learn a lot more from those resources a lot faster.

Comment: I realize. But if I change it from print (B) to print ("B") It has a pattern of number, B, number, B, number etc. So is A and B alternating?

Comment: No, they're not really alternating.  The values of A and B change with respect to each row you're looking at.  A scan of the "matrix" reveals that there are no 0's in it, so A will always be 0.  B will fluctuate between 0 and positive values, since some rows have a 1 in it.

Comment: If I run it with these values:

Comment: matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3],
    [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [7, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
    ]                                                                           I get this as my return:

Comment: [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
[8, 0, 0, 0, 4, 7, 5, 0, 3]
[0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[7, 0, 8, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0]
7
B
4
B
7
B
6
B
8
6
B
7
4
B
7
B

Comment: If you change your print statement from the variable B to the string "B", it'll print "B" instead of what's inside of the variable.

Comment: I realize that. The point of changing it to a "B" was to see which values were Bb and which ones were A. What I found is that they appeared to be alternating. Is this true? If so how do I correct this problem?